# operation returned an invalid status 'bad request' azure cli create management group using a bash script in azure cloud shell

Tags: bash, azure, shell

Have two files config.conf and script.sh

config file has the name to be entered for the management group.
Script just uses that name and creates a management group.

Getting the following error when creating: operation returned an invalid status 'bad request'

```
#config.conf
management_group_name="name"
```

```
#script.sh
#!/bin/bash
. /path/config.conf

#Creates the top management group
az account management-group create --name "$management_group_name" --display-name "$management_group_name"
```

```
username [ ~ ]$ ./script.sh
username [ ~ ]$ 
Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'
```

I used the same code to read the variable from the user and store it and then create the management group that works fine.

Even printing the variable name shows that we are getting the value from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'

Initially, I got the same error in my environment. The error states it cannot fetch the value from **`config.conf`** file.

To fetch the value from config.conf you need to use **`source`** in the **`script.sh`** file.

**`Config.conf`**

```bash
#config.conf
management_group_name="name"
```

**`script.sh`**

```bash
#script.sh
#!/bin/bash
source config.conf

#Creates the top management group
az account management-group create --name "$management_group_name" --display-name "$management_group_name"
```

**`source config.conf`** it will load your configuration file.

**Output:**

```
{
  "children": null,
  "details": {
    "managementGroupAncestors": null,
    "managementGroupAncestorsChain": null,
    "parent": {
      "displayName": "Tenant Root Group",
      "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/3f5c7xxxx",
      "name": "xxxx"
    },
    "path": null,
    "updatedBy": "xxx",
    "updatedTime": "2023-05-19T05:18:30.847141+00:00",
    "version": 1
  },
  "displayName": "xxx",
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/venkat326",
  "name": "xxxx",
  "tenantId": "3f5cxxxxxxx",
  "type": "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups"
}
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried using source and gave the absolute path to the config.conf file and it works!